# Using Min and Max functions inside ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple columns of dates in a Google Sheets spreadsheet (created using arrayformula)
Some values have dates, some are blank.

For each row I want to find the ealiest date, but Min() function does not work inside ArrayFormula(). How to do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHut3.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=query(transpose(query(
{transpose(D2:J)},
"select "&"min(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),min(Col",true,sequence(1,rows(D2:J),1,1)))&") ",
0)),"select Col2",0)
```

the core of the formula is to transpose values so that they are in columns, and then calculate the min(Col1), min(Col2), ... until min(ColX)

### Explanation

1- transpose your array

```
{transpose(D2:J)}
```

2- apply query

3- select min(ColX)
the suite min(ColX) is obtained by

```
min(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),min(Col",true,sequence(1,rows(D2:J),1,1)))
```

4- finally, transpose the result and select only Col2 to erase the labels

Comment: Thank You! I am having trouble understanding it, but it worked when I plugged it in, so thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer with some explanation, especially the third ... try it alone to see the result